# How to use RequestValidator with API Key?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-python

I'm trying to reconcile Twilio's advice and security best practices.

I initially wrote the app using SID and auth-token.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/rest-api-best-practices says:

"we recommend the use of API Keys"

So I'm converting the python helper rest client to initialize using api key/secret

and since this is a webhook auth, following this security practice:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests

Using:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-flask-app-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests

However, this only seems to support auth_token

Does this mean there is no way to use API keys in a webhook app?

It seems silly to bother with API key secrets in app config if I'm also having to set the auth_token secret as well.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio employee here

Looks like you've spotted an inconsistency in our guidance. You are correct: if your app receives incoming webhooks from Twilio and you want to validate the signature of those incoming requests, you cannot use API keys to do so - you must use your account's Auth Token.

I just fixed the first doc you linked to so it reflects that guidance. Thank you for raising this with us and my apologies for the inconsistency in our docs!

Comment: @philnash: Is Twilio planning to support validating signature using API keys?

Comment: As far as I know, request signature validation is still based on the auth token. Sadly I was affected by layoffs at Twilio, so I can't find out any more.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Although my interactions with you have been just on stackoverflow and Twilio, you were always super responsive and helpful and I appreciated that a lot. I wish you the best.

Comment: I just ran into this, this is really unfortunate. Why go through the trouble of creating and using API Keys per project if I'm just going to be required to inject the main API key as well?